# How to use Rewrite in htaccess file when a string appears in the middle of the URL

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, url-rewriting

I need help with formulation of a correct rewrite rule for my htaccess file.

I would like to hide all the attachment pages, so I want to redirect all URLs where "/attachment/" appears to my homepage.

Example:

This URL: https://www.example.com/level/level2/attachment/name/
Should be redirected to: https://www.example.com/

P.S. "level1", "level2" and "name" are always different and I need some generic rule to hide them all.

Thanks!

I tried:

RewriteRule ^/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/attachment/([^/]+)-([0-9]+)/$  / [L,R=301]

And also I tried:

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)attachment(&|$) [NC]
RewriteRule $ https://www.example.com/?  [L,R=301]

But none of them worked.

Comment: Does this work? `RewriteRule .*/attachment/.* / [L,R=301]` If you're trying to match any URL with `/attachment/` anywhere in the string, this should be enough to match them all.

Comment: @drew010 You can simplify that pattern to just `/attachment/` ...

Comment: `RewriteRule .*/attachment/.* / [L,R=301]` this worked! I tried it before with ^ in the beginning but that one totally broke my page, so I threw this solution to bin :) thanks!